# Boto reverse the stream

Tags: python, stream, twisted, boto

I have a server which files get uploaded to, I want to be able to forward these on to s3 using boto, I have to do some processing on the data basically as it gets uploaded to s3.

The problem I have is the way they get uploaded I need to provide a writable stream that incoming data gets written to and to upload to boto I need a readable stream. So it's like I have two ends that don't connect. Is there a way to upload to s3 with a writable stream? If so it would be easy and I could pass upload stream to s3 and it the execution would chain along.

If there isn't I have two loose ends which I need something in between with a sort of buffer, that can read from the upload to keep that moving, and expose a read method that I can give to boto so that can read. But doing this I'm sure I'd need to thread the s3 upload part which I'd rather avoid as I'm using twisted.

I have a feeling I'm way over complicating things but I can't come up with a simple solution. This has to be a common-ish problem, I'm just not sure how to put it into words very well to search it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boto is a Python library with a blocking API.  This means you'll have to use threads to use it while maintaining the concurrence operation that Twisted provides you with (just as you would have to use threads to have any concurrency when using boto ''without'' Twisted; ie, Twisted does not help make boto non-blocking or concurrent).

Instead, you could use txAWS, a Twisted-oriented library for interacting with AWS.  `txaws.s3.client` provides methods for interacting with S3.  If you're familiar with boto or AWS, some of these should already look familiar.  For example, `create_bucket` or `put_object`.

txAWS would be better if it provided a streaming API so you could upload to S3 as the file is being uploaded to you.  I think that this is currently in development (based on the new HTTP client in Twisted, `twisted.web.client.Agent`) but perhaps not yet available in a release.

Comment: If you could write to a writeable stream to s3, then you wouldn't need to thread it I'm pretty sure, you could write a chunks at a time and break it up. Nice point about txawx, I'll look into it

Comment: It's easy to get a writeable stream - create a StringIO or open a real file on disk.  The difficulty you run into is the size of your buffer if S3 doesn't accept data as fast as you are accepting it.

Comment: that buffer will stop the chain of execution though so the s3 part will need to be in a thread. If there was a write on the s3 part, that went into s3 and sent that bit of data, then execution exited back out it could all be done in an async way in a single thread in twisted

Comment: "that buffer will stop the chain of execution though so the s3 part will need to be in a thread." - only if you use boto instead of txaws.  I'm not sure I understand the rest of your comment.  Some concrete code would probably make the issue clearer.

Comment: The S3 service does not support true streaming uploads (i.e. Chunked Transfer Encoding) so you will always need to know the Content-Length of the data you are PUT'ing to S3, regardless of which client you are using.

Comment: You could pass that requirement along downstream to the ultimate client, though.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to wrap the stream in a file like object. So essentially the stream object should have a read method that blocks until the file has been completely uploaded.

After that you just use the s3 API

```
bucketname = 'my_bucket'
conn = create_storage_connection()
buckets = conn.get_all_buckets()
bucket = None
for b in buckets:
    if b.name == bucketname:
        bucket = b
if not bucket:
    raise Exception('Bucket with name ' + bucketname + ' not found')
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = key
k.set_contents_from_filename(MyFileLikeStream)
```

Comment: your code does not seem to explain anything relevant to the question nor to your answer in text. All lines but last one seems rather irrelevant, last line is missing any explanation about MyFileLikeStream and I would guess, it is wrong (you should probably use k.set_contents_from_file, not .._from_filename).